# Clear Freshchat when refreshing page

Tags: c#

Trying to clear the chat after page gets refreshed. I have tried using the code below and keep getting "Something went wrong. You're not connected". 
The chat can be accessed by anyone and the site doesn't have a login feature

```
<script>
        window.fcWidget.user.clear().then(function () {
            console.log('User cleared');
        }, function () {
            console.log("User Not cleared");
        });
</script>

<script>
        window.fcWidget.init({
            "config": {
                "cssNames": {
                    "widget": "chat"
                }
            },
            token: "API_KEY",
            host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com"
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the widget before clearing it.

```
  <script>
        window.fcWidget.init({
            "config": {
                "cssNames": {
                    "widget": "chat"
                }
            },
            token: "API_KEY",
            host: "https://wchat.freshchat.com"
        });
</script>

    <script>
        window.fcWidget.user.clear().then(function () {
            console.log('User cleared');
        }, function () {
            console.log("User Not cleared");
        });
</script>
```

Also might be worth wrapping this in a document.ready()